# ASP.NET App that monitors an external sensor (Multithreading)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

I created an MVC 4 App that gets data from some external sensors, and then shows data depending on the values recived. The external sensors expose their values through an http page (e.g. http:///CheckValue). The MVC App must be continiously checking for those values, let´s say every 5 seconds.

The basic Idea is that this process must be done on the background and in a infinite loop, each sensor on a different thread.

The problem is that I don´t know where is the best place to do this, as of now I just create a new Task for each sensor at the Application_Start method on the Global.aspx file.

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    foreach (var sensor in sensors)
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => sensor.readValue(5000));
    }
}
```

This is the code for readValue()

```
public void readValue(int timespan)
{
    try
    {
        using HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            while(true){
                try
                {
                    string result = await client.GetStringAsync(url);
                    //result validation logic
                }
                catch(Exception)
                {
                    //Exception Handling
                }
                Thread.Sleep(timespan);
            }                 
        }
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.Write(e.Message);
    }
}
```

I´m new to ASP.NET so I really don´t know if this should be in the Application_Start method, or if maybe it shouldn´t be on the MVC App at all, and do it on a separate Windows Service (If so how do I send the values back to the MVC App)

Comment: I would create the MVC page only to show and monitor the values, and use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/) to continuously get and show values from `http:///CheckValue`. SignalR will connect to the exposed URL as long as there's clients seeing the "monitor page".

Comment: The thing is that the values must be continuosly monitored since they also control other stuff on the code, not just when someone is seeing that page

Comment: then you shouldn't use a web page, you should use a service, like a Windows Service as long as the computer is on.

Comment: In that case, how does the service sends the values back to the MVC App?

Comment: you expose them as a Service, and MVC App consumes them... the Windows Service can even log all data, even if you're not monitoring through the web app...